# Last nth digit of an integer

Tags: java

I am having my final exam tomorrow so i am practicing some questions.But i am stuck at this question.

Write a method named getNthDigit that returns the n-th digit of an integer.It should work for negative numbers as well.

Eg.

```
CALL                    VALUE RETURNED
getNthDigit(123,1)      3
getNthDigit(123,2)      2
getNthDigit(123,3)      1
getNthDigit(-123,1)     3
```

My code:

```
public static void getNthDigit(int x,int y){

x=Math.abs(x);
x%10;

}
```

My thought process is everytime i modulo it by 10,it gives me the last digit.But it is still wrong.Like if i call for getNthDigit(123,2) ,i no longer need the last digit value.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of strings, you could do:

```
(Math.abs(x) / Math.pow(10, y - 1)) % 10
```

- `abs(n)` takes care of the negative case.
- `n / 10^(y - 1)` truncates `n` to the first (counting from the left) `y` digits.
- `% 10` gets the last digit of that resulting number.

Comment: ...as long as if you put it in production code you add a comment to explain what it's doing. Not too many people could just look at it and tell.

Comment: @John3136: I was just going off of OP's attempt at using the modulo operator. I would've used a string for this.

Comment: Not picking on the answer - very clever, just pointing out that if I saw this in production code I wouldn't know what it was doing off the top of my head! All depend on the context: school vs work ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Modular arithmetic can be used to accomplish what you want. For example, if you divide `123` by `10`, and take the remainder, you'd get the first digit `3`. If you do integer division of `123` by `100` and then divide the result by `10`, you'd get the second digit `2`. More generally, the n-th digit of a number can be obtained by the formula `(number / base^(n-1)) % base:`

```
public int getNthDigit(int number, int base, int n) {    
  return (int) ((number / Math.pow(base, n - 1)) % base);
}

System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 1));  // 3
System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 2));  // 2
System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 3));  // 1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply convert the number to string and then get the character at the required position ?

```
public static void getNthDigit(int x,int y){
    String str = String.valueOf(x);
    if(str.charAt(0) == '-')
        y++;
    System.out.println(str.charAt(y-1));
}
```

Comment: +1, for a simple solution. Not sure why you got the down vote.

Comment: True.Why did i not think of that.Shall try it out now!Thank!

Comment: @galuano1 can you explain how in a bit more detail ?

Comment: Something that can be done mathematically is usually and in this case is more efficient. You are creating a string and doing String operations, where just doing Math powers will solve the problem.

Comment: @galuano1 The problem does not involve mathematical operations. Digit at a specific location is similar to character at a location. Also the code sample I shared provides a lot more readability.

Comment: @Apurv Look at Blender's solution.

Comment: @galuano1 It is much more complicated to understand while the problem is much simpler -> digit at a position.

Comment: @galuano, The requirement didn't ask for the most efficient solution. The have been 3 different versions of the math related solution, so it is obviously not as simple and straight forward as it appears. The OP can decide which approach they prefer.

Comment: I believe it's the Nth digit from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it into a string, strip off any leading -ve and then just index into the string (handling the fact you want 1 based indexes where Java uses 0 based).

Comment: Technically you don't need to drip the `-`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = String.valueOf(x);
int index = s.length()- y;
char result = s.charAt(index);
```

Comment: Way slow compared to `%` and `/`